# Change all values equal to x to y

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very simple task that I cannot figure out how to do in numpy. I have a 3 channel array and wherever the array value does not equal `(1,1,1)` I want to convert that array value to `(0,0,0)`.

So the following:

```
[[0,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,0,1]]
```

Should change to:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [1,1,1],
 [0,0,0]]
```

How can I achieve this in numpy? The following is not achieving the desired results:

```
# my_arr.dtype = uint8
my_arr[my_arr != (1,1,1)] = 0
my_arr = np.where(my_arr == (1,1,1), my_arr, (0,0,0))
```

Comment: What is your code producing?

Comment: Look at `my_arr==(1,1,1)`.  The result will be boolean array the same shape as `my_arr`.  You don't want `where` on that, do you?  Now try row-wise `all`.  Is that better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.array.all(1)` to filter and assign 0:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,0,1]])
arr[~(arr == 1).all(1)] = 0
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Explain:

- `arr==1`: returns array of `bool`s that satisfy the condition (here it's 1)
- `all(axis=1)`: returns array of `bool`s if each row has all `True` (i.e. all rows that are 1`
- `~(arr==1).all(1)`: selects rows that are **not** all 1

Comment: thanks. Can you explain what `~(arr == 1).all(1)` is doing?

Comment: when I execute this code I get the error: `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 704 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3`

Comment: @JakeM Added some explanation. As for the `IndexError`, I cannot reproduce it. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: @JakeM Replace `.all(1)` with `.all(-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just comparing the two lists.

```
 x = [[0,1,1],
      [1,1,1],
      [1,0,1]]

for i in range(len(x)):

    if x[i] != [1,1,1]:
        x[i] = [0,0,0]
```